# Function in consumer thread unable to access memory location

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, producer-consumer

I have some code that processes images. Performance is critical so I'm tyring to implement multi-threading using `BoundedBuffer`. The image data is stored as `unsigned char*` (dictated by the SDK I'm using to process the image data).

The problem occurs in the `processData` function called in the consumer thread. Inside the `processData`, there is another function (from the image processing SDK) that uses `cudaMemcpy2D` function. The cuda function always throws an exception saying *Access violation reading location.*

However, the cuda function works fine if I call the the `processData` directly within the producer thread or `deposit`. When I call `processData` from the consumer thread (as desired), I get the exception from the cuda function. I even tried calling `processData` from fetch and I got the same exception.

My guess is that after the data is `deposit`ed into the `rawImageBuffer` by the producer thread, somehow the memory pointed to by `unsigned char*` changes, thus the consumer thread (or `fetch`) actually sends bad image data to `processData` (and the cuda function).

This is what my code looks like:

```
void processData(vector<unsigned char*> unProcessedData)
{
    // Process the data
}

struct BoundedBuffer {
    queue<vector<unsigned char*>> buffer;
    int capacity;

    std::mutex lock;

    std::condition_variable not_full;
    std::condition_variable not_empty;

    BoundedBuffer(int capacity) : capacity(capacity) {}

    void deposit(vector<unsigned char*> vData) 
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(lock);

        bool bWait = not_full.wait_for(l, 3000ms, [this] {return buffer.size() != capacity; }); // Wait if full

        if (bWait)
        {
            buffer.push(vData); // only push data when timeout doesn't expire
            not_empty.notify_one();
        }           
    }

    vector<unsigned char*> fetch()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(lock);

        not_empty.wait(l, [this]() {return buffer.size() != 0; }); // Wait if empty

        vector<unsigned char*> result{};

        result = buffer.front();
        buffer.pop();

        not_full.notify_one();

        return result;
    }
};

void producerTask(BoundedBuffer &rawImageBuffer)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        // Produce Data
        vector<unsigned char*> producedDataVec{dataElement0, dataElement1};
        rawImageBuffer.deposit(producedDataVec);
    } //loop breaks upon user interception
}

void consumerTask(BoundedBuffer &rawImageBuffer)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        vector<unsigned char*> fetchedDataVec{};
        fetchedDataVec = rawImageBuffer.fetch();
        processData(fetchedDataVec);
    } //loop breaks upon user interception 
}

int main()
{
        BoundedBuffer rawImageBuffer(6);

        thread consumer(consumerTask, ref(rawImageBuffer));
        thread producer(producerTask, ref(rawImageBuffer), 

        consumer.join();
        producer.join();

        return 0;
}
```

Am I correct in my guess about why the exception is being thrown? How do I resolve this? For reference, each vector element contains data for a 2448px X 2048px image in RGBa 8bit format.

UPDATES:

1. After someone pointed out in the comments that the `unsigned char*` pointers could be invalid, I found that the address pointed by the pointers is in fact a real memory location. In the exception *Access violation reading location* X. X is larger than the location pointed by the pointer.
2. After some more debugging, I've found that the memory pointed to by the `unsigned char*` in `unprocessedData` vector in `processData` doesn't remain intact, the pointer address is correct, but some blocks of memory are unreadable. I found this by printing each `char` in the `unsigned char*` in `processData`. When `processData` is called by producer thread (this is when cuda doesn't throw exception), all `char`s get printed nicely (I'm printing 2048*2448*4 `char`s, dictated by the aforementioned image resolution and format). But when `processData` is called by the consumer thread, printing the `char` throws the same exception, exception is thrown around the 40th `char` (around 40th, not always 40th).
3. Okay, so now I'm pretty sure not only my pointers are pointing to real memory locations, I also know that the first memory block pointed by the pointer holds the expected value for as many times as I've tested this. To test this, in `producerTask` I deliberately write a test value (such as `int` 42, or `char` *) to the `0`th memory block pointed by the `unsigned char*`. In the `processData` function, I check if the memory block still contains the test value and it does. So, now I know some of the memory blocks pointed by the pointer become inaccessible to read for some unknown reason. Also, my test doesn't prove that the first memory block is immune to become inaccessible, just that it didn't become inaccessible for the few number of tests I did. **TLDR for Updates 1 to 3**: The `unprocessedImage` pointers are valid, they point to a real memory address and also they point to the memory address that hold the expected value.
4. Another debugging attempt. Now I'm using Visual Studio's memory window to visually inspect the data. The debugger tells me that `unProcessedData[0]` points to `0x00000279d7c76070`. This is what memory around `0x00000279d7c76070` looks like:
   [image: image_memory_before]
   Memory seems sensible, the `RGBa` format can be clearly seen, the image is all black so it makes sense that the `RGB` channels are close to 0 whereas `alpha` is `ff`. I scrolled down for a long time to see what the memory looks like, all the way till `0x00000279D8F9606F` the data looks good (RGBa values as expected). The `0x00000279D8F9606F` number also makes sense because `0x00000279D8F9606F` - `0x00000279d7c76070` = `0d20054015`, which means there are 20054016 valid `char`s which is expected (2048 height*2448 width*4 channels = 20054016). Okay, so far so good. Note that all this is right before running the cuda function. After stepping through the cuda function I get the same exception: *Access violation reading location `0x00000279D80B8000`*. Note that *`0x00000279D80B8000`* is between `0x00000279d7c76070` and `0x00000279D8F9606F`, the parts of memory which I visually checked to be correct. Now, after running the cuda function here is what the memory between `0x00000279d7c76070` and `0x00000279D8F9606F` looks like:
   [image: image_memory_after]
5. When I `cout` anything in `processData` before calling the cuda function. The memory pointed by the pointer changes. All the `char`s become equivalent to `0xdd` as can be seen in the image below. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) page on MSDN says that `The freed blocks kept unused in the debug heap's linked list when the _CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF flag is set are currently filled with 0xDD.`
   [image: image_memory_change]
   But when I call `processData` from the producer thread, the pointed memory doesn't change after I `cout` anything.

Right now the most upvoted comment to this question is telling me to learn more about pointers. I am doing this currently (hopefully as my updates may suggest), however what topics do I need to learn about them? I do know how pointers work. I know my the pointers are pointing to valid memory location (see Update 2). I know some memory blocks pointed by the pointer become inaccessible to read (see Update 3). But I don't know why the memory blocks become inaccessible. Especially, I don't know why they only become inaccessible when `processData` is called from the consumer thread (note that there is no exception thrown when `processData` is called form the producer thread). Is there anything else I can do to help narrow down this problem?

Comment: If "Performance is critical", what would be the purpose of all this parameter passing by value, wasting time on making utterly redundant, multiple copies of the data?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'd like to get multi-threading working first and then optimize other aspects. If you have any particular suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Is that the data that all these `unsigned char *`s are pointing to? What is there in place to make sure that whatever those pointers are pointing to is valid, and hasn't been deallocated by the time `processData()` gets around to it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think currently there's nothing in place to make sure the pointers are valid, and that might be causing the issue. I don't have a lot of experience with c++ pointers so I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. Sorry, I didn't understand the first question you asked: "Is that the data that all these unsigned char *s are pointing to?"

Comment: Well, then, you might want to spend some time acquiring some "experience" and understanding of how pointers work, before trying to deal with advanced topics like multithreading. This is like trying to launch a rocket into space without having a good grasp on how solid fuel rocket boosters work. If you do not fully understand what those pointers are pointing to, whether the data there is actually valid, by the time some thread looks at it, then I can't think of anything else to suggest, except that.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment, I do understand how pointers work. I mentioned I don't have a lot of experience with them, as I don't know how to programmatically make sure they're valid.

Comment: What are `dataElement0` and `dataElement1` in producerTask? Could your vector be empty?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus They're not empty. I've purposely hid some code to make this more readable. Those are just `unsigned char*`s containing image data. There is a check before the vector is formed to make sure the elements are not empty, I'm using a closed-source camera API for that, that's why it's not shown here.

Comment: You may be dropping slices on the floor because your wait time of 2000 and 3000 are different. Maybe this corrupts the data. wait_for returns a boolean you can use instead. (You also don't need to call notify if you didn't add a vector.) Indeed, maybe you need a loop to be sure something gets added... is it safe to drop out a piece of the picture?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Thanks for pointing that out. I'm using the bool return value now. However, the data still gets corrupted. The reason for having the timeout is to do with implementation details of how the threads stop upon user intervention. Under usual circumstances consumer notifies well before the timeout. The difference in wait times was intentional. I'm pretty sure the timeout doesn't interfere with validity of the data because I've tested it without it.

Comment: Why do you have a vector of pointers, and not just unsigned chars?

Comment: @James My consumer needs a set of unsigned chars. More specifically, the `processData` function needs more than one image at a time because I'm not processing a single image, rather I need to process both at the same time. I say "both" because right now I have two cameras, the consumer needs one image from each camera at the same time. The number of cameras could increase later on.

Comment: Your SDK wanting `unsigned char*` doesn't mean you must have `unsigned char*` splattered throughout your code.

Comment: @n.m. The function I use to acquire images in the producer also returns image data in the form of `void*`

Comment: Why your *miltithreaded buffer*, of all places, should be exposed to these regrettable facts? Wrap your data safely upon collection, unwrap just before passing it further down.

Comment: Anyway, if your memory is accessible before a call to a cuda function, and is inaccessible afterwards,then perhaps the cuda function is to blame. Have you tried to alter/disable/debug it?

Comment: @n.m. The cuda function resides in the SDK dll for which the source code is not public. I'm not fully sure if the data is accessible before the call to cuda function, any `cout` statements cause the data to change to `0xdd` (please see my last update). Note that cuda function works fine when `processData` is called from the consumer thread.

Comment: Why do you think any of the posted code has anything to do with the problem then? You get some `char*s` from an unspecified place (dataElement0, dataElement1) and pass them around (in a vector in a queue in a thread safe buffer buffer, but it isn't clear why is that important) and when time comes to read the data it isn't there. You should find out (1) what components **owns** the data (responsible for its deletion) (2) when this deletion happens (3) whether or not there are buffer overflows or other UB elsewhere that may damage the data.

Comment: If you were on Linux you should have started using valgrind to debug the problem; on Windows I have no idea, perhaps Dr. Memory?

Comment: @n.m. Just to clarify, the `char*s` I'm getting are from another closed-source camera SDK. I'll try following all the 3 points you mentioned and look into Dr. Memory as well. But what does UB mean? Another thing is that the memory remains intact if the pointer points to something small like 10 `chars`.

Comment: UB means undefined behaviour, you will see these words a lot. I think you want to read the SDK documentation again and clarify how and when  buffers that it returns to you are supposed to be freed or reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fairly simple, n.m.'s comments guided me towards the right direction and I'm thankful for that.

In my updates I mentioned that printing anything using `cout` caused the data to become corrupt. Although, it seemed like that was happening, but after putting some breakpoints in `fetch` and `deposit`, I got a complete picture of what was really happening.

The way I produced the image data was by using another SDK supplied with the camera, the SDK provided me with image data in the type of wrapped pointer. Then I converted the image format and then unwrapped converted image to get the pointer to the raw image. Then the pointer to the raw image is stored into `producedDataVec` and `deposit`ed it into `rawImageBuffer`. The problem was that as soon as the converted image went out of scope, my data became corrupted. So, the `cout` statements weren't really responsible for corrupting my data. With breakpoints placed everywhere I could see the data becoming corrupt just after the converted image went out of scope. To resolve this, now my producer directly `deposit`s the wrapped pointer to the buffer. The consumer `fetch`es the wrapped pointer, the converted image is obtained by converting the format in the consumer, and then the raw image pointer is obtained. Now the converted image only goes out of scope after `processData` has returned so the exception is never thrown.

Comment: Putting this side note here as a comment: Some comments to my question were not just condescending but also steered me towards the wrong direction. I understand I don't know as much as most users here on SO, but in the end such comments are harmful as these comments can cause other users to avoid answering the question.